# Excluding product images progamatically

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images

How do you exclude all product images of a product,
 i.e. the **Exclude** box of every image being ticked on the **Images** tab in the Magento backend.

I'm bulk adding new images to products using `$product->addImageToMediaGallery()` but before adding the new pictures I want to exclude the already existing images.

I want exclude them and not remove them so they can easily be restored in the future if needed.

Comment: Just to get sure I understand your question: Given a product with already exiting images a.jpg and b.jpg. You upload c.jpg and a.jpg. Expected behaviour is to upload both images and exclude the second a.jpg, so you have a media gallery with a.jpg, b.jpg and c.jpg and in the backend you have 4 images with the second a.jpg (renamed to a_1.jpg by Magento by default) with checkbox "Exclude" checked?

Comment: The expected behaviour is to exlude the images that are already in Magento. The new uploads replace the old ones, filenames don't have to be renamed.

Expected behaviour:
Already existing images: `a.png`, `b.png`.
New uploads: `c.png`, `d.png`.
Result: `a.png` and `b.png` are exluded, `c.png` and `d.png` are not.

Right now all four images are enabled and I wish to exlude `a.png` and `b.png`. Or basically I'm asking how to exclude an image in general.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can exclude any product image for a given product by using the `updateImage` method from the model `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Attribute_Backend_Media` if you know the filename of the image you want to exclude (filename is the complete path beginning with the slash below media/catalog/product). For example with the following code you can exclude all existing images from the media gallery for the product with id = 12345:

```
$product_id = '12345';

$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
$attributes = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getSetAttributes($product);

if (isset($attributes['media_gallery'])) {
    $mediaGalleryAttribute = $attributes['media_gallery'];
    $media = $mediaGalleryAttribute->getBackend();
    $mediaGalleryData = $product->getData('media_gallery');
    if (isset($mediaGalleryData['images']) && is_array($mediaGalleryData['images'])) {

        foreach ($mediaGalleryData['images'] as $image) {
            $media->updateImage($product, $image['file'], ['exclude' => 1]);
        }
        $product->save();
    }
}
```

Running this code before your `$product->addImageToMediaGallery()` call, should do what you want - maybe it's usefull to add a little more error handling.

There is of course a faster way just by updating the `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value` table, but the approach above is probably the better one for your requirement.

Just to be complete, here the SQL statement for the fastest and simplest solution since you can exclude all images for all your products in one statement:

```
update catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value set disabled = 1 
where value_id in (
      select value_id from catalog_product_entity_media_gallery 
      where entity_id in (12345,12346)  -- list your product_ids here
);
```

Comment: Your first solution executed for me without errors but did not update the records and I have no idea why.

Comment: However, I have fixed my issue by using your raw query. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please find my alternate solution for exclude image if you prefer to keep your code Simple.

```
  $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(1234); //Your Product ID Here
  $mediaApi = Mage::getModel("catalog/product_attribute_media_api");    
  $images = $mediaApi->items($product->getId());  
  foreach ($images as $image) {
     $data = $image;
     $data['exclude'] = 1;
     unset($data['file']);
     $mediaApi->update($product->getId(),$image['file'],$data);     
   }
  $product->save();
```